# Find a file history

Tags: git, history, commit

How do I find in which git commits a certain file was changed? like..

git --when-did-it-change scr/ThatBuggyClass.java

```
88fa9f  (HEAD) last time trying to debug it
99321c  another round with ThatBuggyClass
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log src/ThatBuggyClass.java
```

You can use the `--oneline` switch to format the output like your example:

```
git log --oneline src/ThatBuggyClass.java
```